# what is the chromatic index of this graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

[image]

I am trying to figure out the chromatic index of this graph. I thought that it is 4, however in the solutions that I have it says that the chromatic index is only 3. Which is the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [chromatic index](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EdgeChromaticNumber.html) of this graph is indeed $4$. There are $4$ edges incident on vertex $1$.  So none of them can have the same color, so we have used up $4$ colors. The other portion of the graph does not pose any further problems.

Also see [Vizig's](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/25365/0000813.pdf?sequence=1) theorem.

Answer (score 0):

By Vizing's theorem, the chromatic index of a graph is always either $\Delta$ or $\Delta+1$, where $\Delta$ denotes the maximum degree of the graph. It is well-known that if $G$ is bipartite, its chromatic index is exactly $\Delta$. Your graph is a tree, which is bipartite. Thus, its chromatic index is $\Delta = 4$.